# Spring Integration WS Outbound Gateway Error : InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

Hi I am using Spring Integration WS Outbound gateway to invoke a Soap Service. This is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="CreatePreadvice" targetNamespace="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/" xmlns:isd="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/" xmlns:Q1="http://www.asda.com/PreadviceRequest">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="Preadvice.xsd" namespace="http://www.asda.com/PreadviceRequest"></xsd:import>
            <xsd:element name="createPreadvice">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CreatePreadviceRequest" type="Q1:Preadvice"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="createPreadviceResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CreatePreadviceResponse" type="isd:Response"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

      <xsd:complexType name="Response">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="createPreadviceFault">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="parcelInjectionFault"
                    type="xsd:string">
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="createPreadviceFault1">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="CreatePreadviceResponse"
                    type="isd:Fault">
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>

      <xsd:complexType name="Fault">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Error" type="isd:Error"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>

      <xsd:complexType name="Error">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="createPreadviceRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="isd:createPreadvice" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createPreadviceResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="isd:createPreadviceResponse" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createPreadviceFault">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="isd:createPreadviceFault"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createPreadviceFault1">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="isd:createPreadviceFault1"></wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="CreatePreadvice">
    <wsdl:operation name="createPreadvice">
      <wsdl:input message="isd:createPreadviceRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="isd:createPreadviceResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="isd:createPreadviceFault1"></wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="CreatePreadviceSOAP" type="isd:CreatePreadvice">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="createPreadvice">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/createPreadvice"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="CreatePreadvice">
    <wsdl:port binding="isd:CreatePreadviceSOAP" name="CreatePreadviceSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://161.163.98.135:60719/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

This is the xsd taken from wsdl types that I am using for creating mapping objects from JAXB

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/"
        xmlns:Q1="http://www.asda.com/PreadviceRequest"
        xmlns:isd="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import schemaLocation="Preadvice_new.xsd"
            namespace="http://www.asda.com/PreadviceRequest"></xsd:import>
         <xsd:element name="createPreadvice">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="CreatePreadviceRequest" type="Q1:Preadvice" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="createPreadviceResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="CreatePreadviceResponse" type="isd:Response" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:complexType name="Response">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="createPreadviceFault">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="parcelInjectionFault" type="xsd:string">
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="createPreadviceFault1">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="CreatePreadviceResponse" type="isd:Fault">
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:complexType name="Fault">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ResponseCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Error" type="isd:Error"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:complexType name="Error">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ErrorCode" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:schema>
```

This is the spring integration configuration

```
<int:chain input-channel="createPreadviceServiceRequestChannel"
        output-channel="createPreadviceServiceReplyChannel">
        <ws:header-enricher>
            <ws:soap-action value="http://www.asda.com/CreatePreadvice/createPreadvice" />
        </ws:header-enricher>
        <ws:outbound-gateway
            uri="${returndropoff.parceldroppost.createpreadvice.stubUrl}"
            marshaller="jaxbsoapunmarshaller" unmarshaller="jaxbsoapunmarshaller" />
    </int:chain>

<bean id="jaxbsoapunmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound"
            value="com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Preadvice,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Address,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.ClientDetails,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Consignee,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Consignment,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Consignments,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Consignor,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.ConsumerDetails,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Contact,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Container,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Containers,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Contents,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Header,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Message,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.ParcelAttributes,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Services,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.CreatePreadvice,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.CreatePreadviceFault,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.CreatePreadviceFault1,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.CreatePreadviceResponse,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Error,
com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Fault,com.asda.connect.returnanddropoffs.dto.post.createpreadvice.Response" />
    </bean>
```

and returndropoff.parceldroppost.createpreadvice.stubUrl is the endpoint url.Can anyone please help what is the issue.Why I am getting InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message exception from WS Gateway.

Exception Stacktrace

```
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: InputStream does not represent a valid SOAP 1.1 Message
            at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.createEnvelopeFromSource(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:88)
            at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.getEnvelope(SOAPPartImpl.java:143)
            at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:189)
            ... 279 more
```

Comment: Is your `returndropoff.parceldroppost.createpreadvice.stubUrl` equal to `http://161.163.98.135:60719/` for the `address` from the WSDL? Have you tested the target service with SOAP-UI? Looks like your service returns invalid `Response`. Please, share more StackTrace to sure that the issue is up to the Response.

Comment: Hi Artem...thanks a lot for the pointer ...I examined the response from soap client and it was returning response with soap version 1.2 where as SaajSoapMessageFactory expects 1.1 by default.Configured the same for 1.2 and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

`SaajSoapMessageFactory` uses **SOAP 1.1** by default. Be sure that the service response is in the appropriate version or **1.2**. If the last one you should inject `SaajSoapMessageFactory` bean to the `<ws:outbound-gateway>` with appropriate property:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory"
          p:payloadCaching="true"
          p:soapVersion="#{T(org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion).SOAP_12}"/>
```